# .Net Array or IList<T> from NumPy array in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, numpy, ironclad

Imagine I have a .Net application that supports user extensions in the form of Python modules by embedding IronPython. Using [Ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/), I can allow users to make use of the NumPy and SciPy packages from within their modules. How good is the interop provided by Ironclad? My question is: can I use a NumPy array of type `T` provided by the user's module in the rest of my app that requires an `IList<T>`?

**Edit** To clarify, IronPython exposes any Python enumerable of objects of type `T` as an `IEnumerable<T>` or an `IList<T>`. I'm not sure if NumPy arrays fit in this category. I would rather not have to call `.tolist()` on the NumPy array as the arrays may be quite large.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but you might try on the IronPython mailing list (lists.ironpython.com)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Perhaps I might be doing it the stupid way , but i convert my numpy array into a list and then into a List[T].